# When I resize my window and make it smaller I get this white gap at the bottom of my project

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
body{
    margin-top: 140px;
}
.outline{
    font-size: 75px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 
    0 0 7px #fff,
      0 0 10px #fff,
      0 0 21px #fff,
      0 0 42px #999,
      0 0 82px #999,
      0 0 92px #999,
      0 0 102px #999,
      0 0 151px #999;;
    -webkit-text-stroke:1px white;
  -webkit-text-fill-color:transparent;
}
.container{
    max-width: 400px;
    margin:10vh auto 0 auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 43px 17px grey;
}
#display{
    text-align: right;
    height: 120px;
    line-height: 120px;
    padding-top: 18px;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 200;
    border-left: 1.5px solid #999;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px white;
}

.buttons{
    display: grid;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    border-left: 1px solid #999;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #edebe8;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4,1fr);
    font-weight:200px; 
    color:white;
}

.buttons > div {
    border-top: 2.5px solid #edebe8;
}

.button{
    border:0.5px solid #999;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#equal{
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    font-size: 35px;
    opacity: 0.3;
    color:black;
}

.button:hover{
    background-color: #323330;
    color:white;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.foot{
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    top:200px;
    color:white;
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px white;
}
@keyframes move-twink-back {
    from {background-position:0 0;}
    to {background-position:-10000px 5000px;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes move-twink-back {
    from {background-position:0 0;}
    to {background-position:-10000px 5000px;}
}
@-moz-keyframes move-twink-back {
    from {background-position:0 0;}
    to {background-position:-10000px 5000px;}
}
@-ms-keyframes move-twink-back {
    from {background-position:0 0;}
    to {background-position:-10000px 5000px;}
}

@keyframes move-clouds-back {
    from {background-position:0 0;}
    to {background-position:10000px 0;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes move-clouds-back {
    from {background-position:0 0;}
    to {background-position:10000px 0;}
}
@-moz-keyframes move-clouds-back {
    from {background-position:0 0;}
    to {background-position:10000px 0;}
}
@-ms-keyframes move-clouds-back {
    from {background-position: 0;}
    to {background-position:10000px 0;}
}

.stars, .twinkling {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display:block;
}

.stars {
  background:#000 url(http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/360/images/stars.png) repeat top center;
  z-index:-2;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.twinkling{
  background:transparent url(http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/360/images/twinkling.png) repeat top center;
  z-index:-1;
  -moz-animation:move-twink-back 200s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation:move-twink-back 200s linear infinite;
  -o-animation:move-twink-back 200s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation:move-twink-back 200s linear infinite;
  animation:move-twink-back 200s linear infinite;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Calculator</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/background.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="outline">The Galaxy Calculator</h1>
        <div class="stars"></div>
        <div class="twinkling"></div>
        <section>
            <div class="container">
                <div id="display"></div>
                <div class="buttons">
                    <div class="button">%</div>
                    <div class="button">/</div>
                    <div class="button">C</div>
                    <div class="button">&larr;</div>
                    <div class="button">7</div>
                    <div class="button">8</div>
                    <div class="button">9</div>
                    <div class="button">*</div>
                    <div class="button">4</div>
                    <div class="button">5</div>
                    <div class="button">6</div>
                    <div class="button">-</div>
                    <div class="button">1</div>
                    <div class="button">2</div>
                    <div class="button">3</div>
                    <div class="button">+</div>
                    <div class="button">&plusmn</div>
                    <div class="button">0</div>
                    <div class="button">.</div>
                    <div id="equal" class="button">=</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <footer>
            <p class="foot">&copy;MSA 2021, The Galaxy Calculator; Design by Samee</p>
        </footer>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried fixing the margins however it still leaves a bit of whitespace at the bottom. I tried removing certain elements, adjusting my width and height for different tags to see if it made a difference and still the same. I'm guessing it has something to do with my stars and twinkle div. Also when i check my project in developer tools my html and body tag dont extend to the bottom of the page. Really confused, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've created a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) for you, feel free to edit if anything is wrong.

Comment: To start and fix this, add `html { position: relative; }`. An absolutely positioned element (your star background) uses the closest parent that doesn't have the default of position: static;

Comment: did you mean the margin between the `section` and the `footer`?

Comment: @Reyno How do I copy or run the snippet. Im new to stackoverflow. Appreciate your time

Comment: @ChrisG I did that it does make my html cover the whole page, will try to work from here and see if something happens. Appreciate the help, any other tips I'm all ears

Comment: @mohammadisam I didnt specify any margins between section and footer? So when you run the project and resize the window to make it smaller in height you will see a white gap at the bottom. In full screen it works fine.

Comment: You can run the snippet with the blue button **Run code snippet**. If you want to make changes you can click **Edit** -> **edit the above snippet**

Comment: I dont see your snippet anywhere or does it override my original snippet? I works but I dont see any changes in the code. Sorry for the trouble

Comment: You were just putting your code in the question; Reyno turned it into an actual, runnable snippet. We're not supposed to change questions beyond spelling or other formal issues. Editing a question so the broken code works would be nonsense.

Comment: I see. Thanks alot everyone for all your help. I learned quite a bit from this.  Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had to remove `position:relative` from your `.foot` css rule so that your footer doesn't mess up the layout.

Plus for the background to fit the entire page also when you resize the window, I moved the css property in the body selector:

`background: #000 url(http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/360/images/stars.png) repeat top center;`

But more importantly, the height 100% to work needs a parent with a determined height except for the root element. So the quickest solution was to set `height:100%` to the html element through a css rule.

You can see with your own eyes running the snippet and going full page:

```css
html{
  height: 100%;
}

body{
  margin-top: 140px;
  background: #000 url(http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/360/images/stars.png) repeat top center;
}
.outline{
    font-size: 75px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 
    0 0 7px #fff,
      0 0 10px #fff,
      0 0 21px #fff,
      0 0 42px #999,
      0 0 82px #999,
      0 0 92px #999,
      0 0 102px #999,
      0 0 151px #999;;
    -webkit-text-stroke:1px white;
  -webkit-text-fill-color:transparent;
}
.container{
    max-width: 400px;
    margin:10vh auto 0 auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 43px 17px grey;
}
#display{
    text-align: right;
    height: 120px;
    line-height: 120px;
    padding-top: 18px;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 200;
    border-left: 1.5px solid #999;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px white;
}

.buttons{
    display: grid;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    border-left: 1px solid #999;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #edebe8;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4,1fr);
    font-weight:200px; 
    color:white;
}

.buttons > div {
    border-top: 2.5px solid #edebe8;
}

.button{
    border:0.5px solid #999;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#equal{
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    font-size: 35px;
    opacity: 0.3;
    color:black;
}

.button:hover{
    background-color: #323330;
    color:white;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.foot{
    /*position: relative;*/
    text-align: center;
    top:200px;
    color:white;
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px white;
}

/*-------------------------------------------*/

@keyframes move-twink-back {
    from {background-position:0 0;}
    to {background-position:-10000px 5000px;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes move-twink-back {
    from {background-position:0 0;}
    to {background-position:-10000px 5000px;}
}
@-moz-keyframes move-twink-back {
    from {background-position:0 0;}
    to {background-position:-10000px 5000px;}
}
@-ms-keyframes move-twink-back {
    from {background-position:0 0;}
    to {background-position:-10000px 5000px;}
}

@keyframes move-clouds-back {
    from {background-position:0 0;}
    to {background-position:10000px 0;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes move-clouds-back {
    from {background-position:0 0;}
    to {background-position:10000px 0;}
}
@-moz-keyframes move-clouds-back {
    from {background-position:0 0;}
    to {background-position:10000px 0;}
}
@-ms-keyframes move-clouds-back {
    from {background-position: 0;}
    to {background-position:10000px 0;}
}

.stars, .twinkling {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display:block;
}

.stars {
  /*backgbackgroundround:#000 url(http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/360/images/stars.png) repeat top center;*/
  z-index:-2;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.twinkling{
  background:transparent url(http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/360/images/twinkling.png) repeat top center;
  z-index:-1;
  -moz-animation:move-twink-back 200s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation:move-twink-back 200s linear infinite;
  -o-animation:move-twink-back 200s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation:move-twink-back 200s linear infinite;
  animation:move-twink-back 200s linear infinite;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Calculator</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">        
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="outline">The Galaxy Calculator</h1>
        <div class="stars"></div>
        <div class="twinkling"></div>
        <section>
            <div class="container">
                <div id="display"></div>
                <div class="buttons">
                    <div class="button">%</div>
                    <div class="button">/</div>
                    <div class="button">C</div>
                    <div class="button">&larr;</div>
                    <div class="button">7</div>
                    <div class="button">8</div>
                    <div class="button">9</div>
                    <div class="button">*</div>
                    <div class="button">4</div>
                    <div class="button">5</div>
                    <div class="button">6</div>
                    <div class="button">-</div>
                    <div class="button">1</div>
                    <div class="button">2</div>
                    <div class="button">3</div>
                    <div class="button">+</div>
                    <div class="button">&plusmn</div>
                    <div class="button">0</div>
                    <div class="button">.</div>
                    <div id="equal" class="button">=</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <footer>
            <p class="foot">&copy;MSA 2021, The Galaxy Calculator; Design by Samee</p>
        </footer>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I already have this working on full screen. But when I resize and make the window smaller the gap keeps increasing. Removing the position does decrease the gap but its still there. Appreciate any further assistance, thank you for taking the time

Comment: I moved the background in the body and the window resize doesn't affect the layout anymore.. is it correct?

Comment: Yup that works, however my stars do no animate in the region that had the whitespace. Its not a huge deal but if there is a way to preserve that it would be awesome. Thanks for your help im finally getting somewhere

Comment: your `div.twinkling` was not taking the `height:100%` because the html root element wasn't set to `height:100%`. Problem solved